# Remove standard page number placement, & new type of page number display

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, footer

I am trying to get rid of the automatic page numbering in my LaTeX document. I am using `article` as my document class, and I think page numbering is automatically included here. But instead of this, I want to use this footer: `\rfoot{Page \thepage \hspace{1pt} of \pageref{LastPage}}`

[image: Bottom of my document page]

As you see, I get double page numbering. How do I solve this?

Comment: (1) welcome to the site. (2) Please provide a full but minimal example which shows your problem, but can also be copied by others to be tested elsewhere. I would assume that the `fancyhdr` has in is manual how to clear the other fields (you only set the right one using `\rfoot`

Comment: \cfoot{} would clear the middle section of the foot but the suggestion in the answer posted to clear everything first is good.

Answer (score 3):

Defining the style `fancy`  you first begin clearing all other headers in use with `\fancyhf{}`.

[image: f]

This code is a minimum guide.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{kantlipsum} % dummy text

\fancyhf{} %clear all fancy headers
\fancyfoot[R]{Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}} 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % no rule
\pagestyle{fancy} % apply the style fancy

\begin{document}

    \section{Section A}
    
    \kant[4-8]      
    
    \section{Section BC}    
    \kant[2-5]      

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this was very helpful :)